# Need to convert this for loop to a while loop

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I solved a problem recently. But I have this one piece of code where I dont utilize the for loop initialization and condition check. It looks a bit odd that way for a for loop. I want to convert it into a while loop. Please help me do it. I tried many times, but somewhere something is missing.

```
for(;;current =(current+1)%n){
    if(eliminated[current%n]){
        continue;
    }else{
        inkiPinki++;
        if(inkiPinki == m){
            eliminated[current%n] = true;
            printStatus(eliminated, people);
            remainingGuys--;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code eliminiated[index] is a boolean.

**Edit**: Thanks to Geoff who provided me with a solution which I further minimized like this.

```
while( eliminated[current] || ++inkiPinki != m )
    current = (current+1) % n;
eliminated[current] = true;
printStatus( eliminated, people );
remainingGuys--;
```

Comment: Why do you need this a `while`? Maybe you want just to simplify this loop?

Comment: From your edit, I'm not sure what you want anymore? This code belongs inside the loop surely?

Comment: The edit I've done is how the final output should look like. Lesser code as possible. But I have erred somewhere in that while loop. Logically my program is failing

Comment: this should be one if-statement without looping.  do you require the side effect of inkiPinki to be incremented until it hits m?  have you observed this code to non-terminate?

Comment: @Ron: This code works fine (the one with the for loop). I want to exactly translate it in a while loop and as much lesser code as possible

Comment: @Bragaadeesh Am I right that you are doing something like inner loop of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem ?

Comment: @All : This is the final program I arrived at

http://www.technicalypto.com/2010/04/find-last-person-seated-around-in.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
while( true ) {
    if( !eliminated[current] ) {
        if( ++inkiPinki == m ) {
            break;
        }
    }
    current = (current+1) % n;
}
eliminated[current] = true;
printStatus( eliminated, people );
remainingGuys--;
```

It should be logically equivalent.

Comment: This i tried, but the last line current = (current+1)%n execution wont happen if it encounters continue

Comment: Do you just mean that you want printStatus outside the loop?

Comment: Revised the answer a little, it's pretty simple now, I don't see that any more needs/wants removed from it.

Comment: Yep, its working now!! Thanks.. i guess it can be further reduced.. Thank you anyway, i will take from here

Comment: while( eliminated[current] || ++inkiPinki != m )
        current = (current+1) % n;
    eliminated[current] = true;
    printStatus( eliminated, people );
    remainingGuys--;

Answer (score 2):

All for loops can be converted to while loops using the following pattern:

```
for (..xxx..; ..yyy..; ..zzz..) {
  ..aaa..
}
```

becomes

```
...xxx...
while (...yyy...) {
  ..aaa..
  ..zzz..
}
```

remember that

```
for (;;) {
  ..aaa..
}
```

is equivalent to

```
for (nop; true; nop) {
  ..aaa..
}
```

where "nop" means no operations.

In your example this makes your loop:

```
for(;;current =(current+1)%n){
    if(eliminated[current%n]){
        continue;
    }else{
        inkiPinki++;
        if(inkiPinki == m){
            eliminated[current%n] = true;
            printStatus(eliminated, people);
            remainingGuys--;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

equivalent to

```
// no initialzation needed
while(true) {
    //if(eliminated[current%n]){
    //    continue;
    //}else{
    if(!eliminated[current%n]){
        inkiPinki++;
        if(inkiPinki == m){
            eliminated[current%n] = true;
            printStatus(eliminated, people);
            remainingGuys--;
            break;
        }
    }
    current =(current+1)%n;
}
```

From there, you can simplify it further, if you wish.

Comment: doesn't the 'continue' in the loop body break your transformation?

Comment: Gotta watch that continue doesn't cause a skip in updating when transforming a for to another loop; I corrected the code, because with it corrected it's the best answer, since it most closely resembles the original and I wanted to upvote it.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Yes, the continue in the loop body broke the transformation.  I must have needed an extra cup of coffee when I was writing that one, and thanks again for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

How I would do it:

```
while (inkiPinki < m) {
    if (!eliminated[current % n]) {
        inkiPinki++;

        if (inkiPinki == m) {
            eliminated[current % n] = true;
        }
    }

    if (inkiPinki < m) {
        current = (current + 1) % n;
    }
}

printStatus(eliminated, people);
remainingGuys--;
```

This code accomplishes exactly the same thing as your original for loop, except it uses logical tests to determine whether or not it should continue to loop. There's no need for `continue` or `break`. If you find yourself using either of these statements, there's probably some refactoring that should be done.

Comment: Can you please qualify "it's not working"? Also, could you please try again, with the current revision?

Comment: Hi, i tried now still its failing.. Thank you for your efforts

Comment: It also doubles up the exit test, which is error prone (and inefficient, at the risk of being accused of premature optimization).

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have an inordinate fondness for using Booleans as integers:

```
for (;inkiPinki<m; inkPinki += !eliminated[current])
    current = (current + 1) %n;

eliminated[current] = true;
printStatus(eliminated, people);
remainingGuys--;
```

I've also changed `current%n` to simply `current` in a couple of places, because the `%n` is already done where current is incremented, so `current` should already be reduced modulo `n`.

If I were doing it, I'd probably change the sense, so instead of `eliminated`, it was something like `remaining`:

```
for (;inkiPinki<m; inkPinki += remaining[current])
    current = (current + 1) %n;

remaining[current] = false;
printStatus(remaining, people);
remainingGuys--;
```